# when activity starts service, data in activity cannot be delivered to service immediately

Tags: android, service, event-bus

**08-16 21:11:29.053 10913-10913/com.oyyx.servicetest D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class com.oyyx.servicetest.TestAction
08-16 21:11:29.053 10913-10913/com.oyyx.servicetest D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent**

look like eventbus find subscribe method earlier than creating service

---

```
    @OnClick(R.id.start_service)
public void startService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    TestAction testAction = new TestAction();
    testAction.setString("startService");
    startService(intent);
    BusProvider.getInstance().post(testAction);
}
```

//start service and post data(Activity)

```
    @Subscribe
public void testAction(TestAction testAction) {
    Log.e(TAG, testAction.getString());
}
```

//try to receive data(service)

**08-16 09:58:45.987 1507-1507/com.oyyx.servicetest E/MY SERVICE: onCreate executed
08-16 09:58:45.987 1507-1507/com.oyyx.servicetest E/MY SERVICE: onStartCommand executed**

click start service button log **first** and data cannot be delivered.

**08-16 10:02:25.297 1507-1507/com.oyyx.servicetest E/MY SERVICE: 
*startService*
08-16 10:02:25.297 1507-1507/com.oyyx.servicetest E/MY SERVICE: onStartCommand executed**

click start service button **twice** and data come in.

Comment: Instead of using a EventBus, you can pass the TestAction as Intent-arguments to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EventBus library? If yes, try to use sticky event.

```
@OnClick(R.id.start_service)
public void startService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    TestAction testAction = new TestAction();
    testAction.setString("startService");
    BusProvider.getInstance().postSticky(testAction);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Refer [sticky events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,i find eventbus will find subscribe method before creating service.So when data wants to be delivered,just using intent....